# Including appendices problem

Tags: sectioning, appendices

How to create an appendices chapter in a proper way?
Currently I am using the following code:

```
\begin{appendix}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}

\chapter{appendices}\label{ch:appendices}
\section {aaa}
\section {bbb}

\end{appendix}
```

But I have a problem! LaTeX is verifying the appendices as CHAPTER A in the list of content. How do I get rid of CHAPTER A?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) `:)` You don't need to sign your questions, your name automatically appears at the bottom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\appendix` is a declaration and not an environment.

I'd say that

```
\appendix
\chapter*{Appendices}
\markboth{Appendices}{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{A.\arabic{section}}
```

should solve your problem. The sections will be numbered `A.1`, `A.2` and so on.

Comment: Thanks, it's working just fine. Now, the Appendices chapter appears before references. How I can make it appears after it?

Comment: How I can insert another sections begin with B.1, B.2? I modified the code to \renewcommand{\thesection}{B.\arabic{section}}, but it gives me B.3 after the previous A.2

Comment: @Aymen In case of more than one appendix, usually one doesn't say simply "Appendices", but rather `\chapter{TitleA}`, `\chapter{TitleB}` and so on. Otherwise your reader won't have clues why the numbering has changed.

Comment: OK, but how about the ordering of Appendices and references? I want Appendices to appear at the end of the document.

Comment: @Aymen Usually the bibliography comes last, so it's easier to find it when consulting the document.